# The speed of objects in the thread is not accurate

Tags: java, android, multithreading, game-loop

I have a MainThread class which works as a game loop. then in my panel, I have these rectangles which are notes and lines which are barlines for a music sheet (I parse a Music XML file and draw these based on the parsed data), I also parse the tempo and I want these to be moved according to the tempo. I have a function updateX(float x) which updates the x position of the objects. By the start of the thread, I set a variable startTime = System.CurrentTimeMillis() and then I calculate elapsedTime = System.CurrentTimeMillis() - startTime. then delta x is just velocity*elapsedTime where velocity = (the length of a measure/number of beats) * (60000 millis/tempo). But the problem is that when I test it with a metronome, it is not accurate. Also, the notes (rectangles) tend to move a bit faster than the lines. here is mainthread:

```
public class MainThread extends Thread{
public static final int MAX_FPS = 30;
private double averageFPS;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private PlayPanel playPanel;
private boolean running;
public static Canvas canvas;

public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, PlayPanel playPanel) {
    super();
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    this.playPanel = playPanel;
}
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture;

long tick = 0;
int count = 1;
public void start() {

    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            canvas = null;

            if (metronomeOn) {
                if (tick == 0) {
                   // System.out.println(TAG + " Running " + tick + " " + 60000/tempo);
                    if (count % beat == 1) {
                        sendMidi(0x99, 77, 64);
                      //  System.out.println("TICK");
                    } else {
                        sendMidi(0x99, 76, 64);
                      //  System.out.println("TACK");
                    }
                    count++;
                    tick++;

                } else if (tick >= 600/tempo - 1) {
                    tick = 0;
                } else {
                   // System.out.println(TAG + " Running " + tick + " " + 60000/tempo);
                    tick++;
                }
            } else if (!metronomeOn) {
                tick = 0;
                count = 1;
            }

            try {
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                playPanel.update();
                playPanel.draw(canvas);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    try {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

   scheduledFuture =
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}


public void cancel() {
    scheduledFuture.cancel(true);
}
```

here is the updateX functions:

```
// updates the x_position of the notes
public void updateX(float x) {
    rectangle.set(x, rectangle.top, x+rectangle.width(), rectangle.bottom);
    rectangle2.set(x, rectangle2.top, x+rectangle2.width(), rectangle2.bottom);
    if (ledger != null) {
        ledger.updateX(x);
    }
}

// updates the x position of the lines
public void updateX(float x) {
    startX = x;
    stopX = x;
}
```

and the update function:

```
 // updates the notes with the given speed
public void update(float s, long startTime) {
    float elapsedTime = (float)(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
    //System.out.println(TAG + "elapsed time float: " + elapsedTime + " elapsed time long " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    for (Notes n : notes) {
        n.decrementX(s * elapsedTime);
    }
```

Anyone knows why this happens or have any solutions for it?
thanks in advance.

to add, I have implemented a metronome using countDownTimer and that is accurate based on the tempo so I wonder If I could implement the gameloop using the countDownTimer?!

Comment: Use [`System.nanoTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) to measure elapsed time. It's not about the precision (which actually may not be present, anyway), it's explicitly documented to be used for measuring elapsed time.

Comment: @AndyTurner I have also tried that but it still is not accurate

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.sleep` is not accurate enough for your purpose. When a thread gets out of sleep, it may not be scheduled to execute immediately. The time between the end of sleep and resuming execution is undefined, e.g. depending on how busy the system is at the moment.

I suggest that you look into `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()`. You can configure it to run your update code at fixed intervals. It will likely do a better job at measuring time than your own while loop.

Comment: I looked into `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()` but I am lost on how to use it. so I set a runnable with the run method above without the while loop and then I set the `scheduledFuture =
                scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 60000/tempo, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` but this does not work. Can you help me? tnx

Comment: so I set the rate to 1 milliseconds, but still, rectangles move faster (proceed the lines) and the timing is not right. What I mean by that is that I am testing it with a file with 100 quarter notes with a tempo of 60bpm, so every second it should play a note, but it is not on beat

Comment: Add logging to the beginning of your run method, to ensure that it does get called every second. If that's the case, then the out-of-sync behavior is caused by something else.  What controls the line movement?

Comment: this function 
`// updates the barlines according to the given speed
    public void update(float speed, long startTime) {
        float elapsedTime = (float)(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        for (Line ln : barLines) {
            ln.decrementX(speed * elapsedTime);
        }
    }`

Comment: and decrementX is:
`public void decrementX(float x) {`
       ` startX -= x;`
      `  stopX -= x;`
   ` }`

Comment: the logging shows that it is called every second, however, it is not accurate up to milliseconds for example 
`06-20 17:30:48.644 9080-9176/com.balute.etarlearn I/System.out: MainThread Running`
`06-20 17:30:49.646 9080-9176/com.balute.etarlearn I/System.out: MainThread Running`

Comment: How fine grained is your system clock?

Comment: The timer is as accurate as it gets. The two entries you posted are only off by 2 ms. Is there any particular reason you don't want to update the barlines and notes within the same code, so that they will always be in-sync?

Comment: @jingx thanks for asking that question! it solved the problem and they are now in sync.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your "math" for calculating the distance is wrong, you should not add pieces of time, but just calculate the time elapsed from start. You need to set the exact position, remove any code that is adding or decrementing position - it needs a lot of refactor, but will simplify your code, I can't do it because you didn't post the entire code and it is too much of work and you can do it yourself :) Here is an example of code that shows the idea how to do it in a correct way:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ExactPositionBasedOnTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final long speed = 100; // in pixels per second

        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                int xPosition = (int) ((elapsedTime * speed) / 1000);
                updateXPosition(xPosition);

            }
        };

        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(updater, 0, 1000 / 30, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }

    private static void updateXPosition(int xPosition) {
        // set the position, not add anything, just set it !!!
        System.out.println("the xPosition is: " + xPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: But isn't `int xPosition = (int) ((elapsedTime * speed) / 1000);` only the change in position (displacement)? so shouldn't it be relative to the initial position? More exact, let's say the object's x position is 100 and after a second it should go to 200 but your way it will go to 100 bc `xposition = (1000ms*100)/1000 = 100`. I am not sure maybe I did not understand what you mean exactly.

Comment: Yes, but if you would like to start from 100, then simply add 100 to the calculation of xPosition.

Comment: All the thing with your code is that you don't count the whole time that you should, you add parts of x movement (rounded) from inaccurate mesaure of lapsed time (it is tricky to do it right in this way) - this creates the "missing time" and "rounding errors" which then appear as the smaller speed than you need. That is why i give you another way to do it instead of fixing your code, I can't even fix it, it is broken by desing.

Comment: I see now what you mean. I tried it but the movement wasn't smooth, idk maybe there are bugs somewhere else in my code. Also as I am new to coding, what would be some advice you can give me regarding design as you said it is broken, how can I improve it? I will appreciate your input and tnx for your help :)